# Bash script to sort JPEGs after pixelWidth

Tags: bash

I'm trying to sort a folder on a Mac with hundreds of jpgs into separate folders
after their `pixelWidth` with `/usr/bin/sips`. When I run the script it shows an
`Error 4: no file was specified`. The variable `$f` is empty in the first line?
I thought the "f" in `for f in *jpg` referred to the file as it loops through the folder.

```
imgWid=$( /usr/bin/sips -g pixelWidth $f | sed -n 2p | cut -d":" -f2- )  

for f in *jpg; do if [ "$1" == "$imgWid" ]; then; mv $f $dir1 2>/dev/null; fi; done
```

I would appreciate help on how I can fix this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$()` runs the command at the point specified. (So line 1), `$f` is only defined in the loop (line 3).

Maybe:

```
function determineImageWidth()
{
    /usr/bin/sips -g pixelWidth $1 | sed -n 2p | cut -dj":" -f2-
}

for f in *.jpg
do
    width=$(determineImageWidth $f)
    if [ -n $width ] 
    then
        mkdir -p $width
        mv $f $width/
    else
        echo "Can't determine the width for $f"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried your suggestions with no luck yet. The trace still shows empty variable. Just to clarify what I think my problem is :). The the current directory contains lots of jpgs of fex. 3 known widths. So I'd planned on using positional parameters `$1 $2 $3` to `mkdir width$1` etc. to receive the relevant jpgs and letting the loop finish. If you have any other ideas please get back to me.

Comment: @johne I'd suggest creating the directories as required, so you don't need to pass in correct arguments to the code. Please post your updated code, and the output from `bash -x <your script>` so that we can see what is happening.

Comment: `@douglas` I apoligize I must have mistyped your code in yesterdays attempt. I tried again this morning and your script just ripped through those jpgs. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what $f is in the first line of your script. As far as I can see it is just specified within the for loop.
You might want to change $f to $1 in the first line, to use an argument given to your script.